# Поиск зацикленности в списке

Tags: c#, алгоритм, .net

Допустим, есть список или массив, мы берём определённый его элемент, необходимо знать, не ссылается ли он на другой элемент из этого списка, то есть нет ли зацикленности. (Самый очевидный ответ - перебор с помощью цикла - не подходит, так как длина списка может быть очень велика. Этот вопрос задали на собеседовании.) Буду признателен за код (например, на C#).

Comment: А в элементах списка можно данные хранить какие-нибудь?
Что значит "перебор с помощью цикла не подходит"?  В любом случае как минимум один раз списак придется прочитать.

Comment: Да данные там какие-то естественно хранятся , нужен какой-то более эфективный способ и он есть, мне сказали подумай на досуге, возможно спросят на 2 этапе...

Comment: Вопрос задан не очень понятно. Так требуется понять "есть ли ссылка?" или "есть ли цикл?"

Comment: Нужна проверка списка на зацикливание, тоесть ссылается ли один элемент списка на любой другой(этого жэ списка), каждый раз как нам надо будет проверить некий элемент, перебирать огромный список не эффективно.

Comment: список отсортированный?

Answer (score 4):

есть классический алгоритм, когда по списку пускаем 2 указателя, один за шаг переходит на 1 элемент вперед, 2-й - на 2 элемента вперед. При проходе 2-м проверяем, если он указывает на тот-же объект, что и первый - значит цикл есть.

Comment: А если скажем 15 указывает на 1?

Comment: К слову, на Википедии есть официально запиленная статья [cycle detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection), там картинки, примеры, псевдокод.

Comment: Сказано же - перебор отпадает сразу.

Comment: Я так понял, что отпадает перебор с попарным сравнением, у алгоритма Флойда сложность поменьше будет. Или как вы себе представляете работу со списком *ВООБЩЕ* без циклов?

Comment: Сейчас думаю с помощью LINQ попробовать. Найти элементы с таким же
значением как у взятого нами элемента, а затем сравнить их по ссылке.
Не уверен, но может как вариант...

Comment: а Вы думаете Linq будет работать без перебора? Linq при работе с объектами - это просто синтаксическая обертка для тех же циклов

Answer (score -2):

Массив в принципе не может быть зациклен. Вы курите! Список можно проверить ТОЛЬКО пробежав его до конца и проверив нет ли ссылки на какой нибудь элемент этого списка. Как вариант еще можно попробовать хранить количество элементов в списке и попробовать просто пробежать его и если вы вышли за размер - он зациклен.

Могу только предположить, что если у вас каким то образом так оказалось, что вся куча у вас в стеке, то можно искать ссылки на элементы списка. Если у любого из элементов более 1 ссылки то возможно зациклен. Еще есть вариант если у вас двусвязный список - пытаться пройти на встречу.

Comment: Можно поподробнее(желательно с кодом), допустим мы проверили один элемент он ссылается на тот же объект, что и другой элемент списка.
Затем нам понадобится выяснить тоже самое насчёт другого элемента, что опять пробегаться по всему списку?(он очень велик)

Comment: если у вас цель поверить зациклен или нет - достаточно найти один такой случай

Comment: Нет, не один случай, один разок можно было бы и пробежаться...

Comment: ну в любом случае у вас только 2 варианта зацикленности либо конец с началом либо конец в середину

Comment: сейчас написал код с использованием LINQ ,который находит элементы
одинаковые по значению и затем сравниваю их по ссылке с помощью ReferenceEquals ,но он почему-то сравнивает их по значению.

Comment: Мне кажется вы не понимаете структуру списков или объясняете не корректно.